# Achieve "all-or-nothing" transaction between Oracle and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, oracle12c, two-phase-commit

I have an usecase(migrate data from Oracle to MongoDB via Java app) where I required to implement transaction management to ensure "all-or-nothing" in the datastore.

1. Read the input data from Oracle Table (eg: sourcetable).
2. Execute two separate stored procedure with that input and process the output cursor and construct two different Mongo document (that get interested into two different collections in a same datasource[collection1 & collection2] respectively).
3. If the above steps completed successful then update the above Oracle table (eg: sourcetable) with the status as migration successful.
4. Perform commit(both MongoDB & Oracle) only if all the above steps completed successfully.
5. If any error at any step perform Rollback on the entire transaction.

I see  Oracle offers [Two Phase Commit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/ds_txns003.htm) and MongoDB offers [Distributed Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) to achieve these things separately but,I was looking for the way to achieve it together. Also, I have no clue on how to implement it or is that the right solution to my use case or not. I really appreciate for any guidance or pseudo code implementation.

Note: All these process will execute in a distributed environment.

Comment: Are you using Spring? I know there is transaction support in Spring data: https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586687/mongodb-and-mysql-transaction-in-a-distributed-transaction

Comment: MongoDB "distributed" transactions aren't distributed in the XA sense, only in the "special Mongo-only" sense.

Comment: Thanks Fermi, tgdavies and Chrylis for taking time and checking. Am also exploring a way to solve it via programmatic way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article explaining how to do distributed transactions across different kinds of databases: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-a-distributed-transaction-across-mysql-redis-and-mongo-9f6c7448b3b5

MongoDB do not support XA, so [dtm-labs/dtm](https://github.com/dtm-labs/dtm) provide Saga pattern to solve the problem like this. If you want more control on data isolation, you can use TCC pattern instead of Saga pattern.